# sybase ISNULL - are the conditions too long?

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to unmangle a very old variable.  It was a full name entered all in one field and is found in two separate tables.  In most newer places the name is in three logical columns, first, middle, last.  In these it is all together and I am trying to strip it out to first initial, last name.  I found the following here and modified it:

http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/365656-find-last-word-string.html

```
 DECLARE @full_name VARCHAR(20)
 DECLARE @fullname VARCHAR(20)
 SELECT @full_name = REVERSE('John A Test')
 SELECT @fullname = REVERSE('Joe Q Public')

 SELECT @final = ISNULL(
                 (right(@full_name,1) + '.  ' + (REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@full_name, 1, 
                                                   CHARINDEX(' ',@full_name) - 1)))), 

                  (right(@fullname,1) + '.  ' + (REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@fullname, 1, 
                                                   CHARINDEX(' ',@fullname) - 1 ))))
                        )
```

When I leave full_name there it works fine...returns `J. Test`.  When I null it the default should be
`J. Public` but instead ends up as `.`.   When I test each line separately they work.  I tried COALESCE as well with the same results.   Is this too many brackets for ISNULL or  ????

Comment: I doubt it is because the "conditions are too long". This would (or should) result in a nice explicative from the server.

Comment: I didn't think so since it did give me an answer.  Just not what I was expecting.  It should work......?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with `right(@full_name,1) + '.  '`, for example:

`select null+'.'`

gives you `.`.

Try to change your code using `case` as below:

```
 DECLARE @full_name VARCHAR(20)
 DECLARE @fullname VARCHAR(20)
 DECLARE @final VARCHAR(20)
 SELECT @full_name = null--REVERSE('John A Test')
 SELECT @fullname = REVERSE('Joe Q Public')

 SELECT @final = case
                    when @full_name is not null
                       then (right(@full_name,1) + '.  ' + (REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@full_name, 1, 
                                                   CHARINDEX(' ',@full_name) - 1))))
                    else (right(@fullname,1) + '.  ' + (REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@fullname, 1, 
                                                   CHARINDEX(' ',@fullname) - 1 ))))
                 end 
select @final
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  So the first argument isn't really NULL since it has the `'. '` in it, correct? It never gets a chance to default to the second argument.  I tested this and it was showing the `'. '` from the first one sure enough.

Comment: Yes, it's right. It's weird, but it is sybase :), for example in ms sql server `select null+'.'` it's null.